# iPhone UILabel text soft shadow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uilabel, shadow

I know soft shadows are not supported by the UILabel out of the box, on the iPhone. So what would be the best way to implement my own one?

**EDIT:**

Obviously I will subclass the `UILabel` and draw in the -drawRect:
My question is, how do I get the contents of the label as graphics and draw around them, blur them etc...

**EDIT 2:**

I returned to this question about a year later. In the meantime I've built a class that allows you to easily add soft shadow to a label and tweak it's radius etc and also to draw gradients on the text itself. You can find it on GitHub: https://github.com/doukasd/iOS-Components/tree/master/Views

Comment: how to implement this is Base SDK4.0 ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274168/drop-shadow-on-uitextfield-text/1537079#1537079) to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274168/drop-shadow-on-uitextfield-text) provides code for drawing a blurred shadow behind a UILabel.  The author uses CGContextSetShadow() to generate the shadow for the drawn text.

Comment: That's great and it works as advertised! Thanks.
But do you have an idea how I can make that shadow more intense?
Since it part of the context, I can't draw it more than once, which would do the trick.

Comment: You could change the color to be black with a 100% opacity (in his example, it's only 80%), as well as change the shadow radius within the CGContextSetShadow() call.  You might also try shifting the offset from the 4,-4 position that he's set.

Comment: Yes I have tried 100% opacity etc. And regarding the size, the larger you set it to be, the less visible the shadow is... I am looking for something similar to the Shadow Effect in Flash, which you can set to more than 100%.

Comment: how to implement this is Base SDK4.0 ?

Comment: @Apple - What's wrong with the code there? Everything in the linked answer still works today on current iOS versions.

Comment: it is not working properly in IOS 4.0 color gradient is show error because its shows there is 0 object in color array but same code is working properly in IOS above 4.3

Answer (score 191):

As of 3.2 there is direct support for shadows in the SDK.

```
label.layer.shadowColor = [label.textColor CGColor];
label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
```

`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and play with some parameters:

```
label.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;
label.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
```

And, if you find your shadow clipped by the label bounds:

```
label.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

finally set

```
label.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

Comment: Note that to use shadowRadius you have to include the QuartzCore headers:

`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: For some reason this has no effect on my UILabel

Comment: + 1 for the maskToBounds extra info.

Comment: maskToBounds is by default NO, and please edit your example because shadowRadius = 20 is VERY high, so might seen not working (like my case and maybe also for @Pascalius). even 3 (the default) is a bit too much for small labels.

Comment: ty, updating w/ your suggestions

Comment: The shadow is so soft that is sometimes difficult to notice :(

Comment: Also - I have found that you need to set the background color of the label to clearColor, or you will not see the shadow.

Comment: May want to add that you can do the same with the User Defined Runtime Attributes in IB.

Comment: What will happen if you set `shouldRasterize` to false?

Comment: If you plan on using `shouldRasterize`, then make sure you also set the `rasterizationScale` : `label.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;` Or it may look weird on retina screens.

Answer (score 38):

I advise you to use the shadowColor and shadowOffset properties of UILabel:

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1);
```

Comment: Thank you but yes. I was actually looking for *soft* shadow.

Comment: For "soft" shadow - maybe you can change color properly?

for example, i needed "soft" dark shadow. - as blackColor was too sharp, i ended up with grayColor :) 
Happy coding! :)

Comment: He means a blurry shadow, without sharp edges.

Answer (score 17):

Additionally to IIDan's answer:
For some purposes it is necessary to set

```
label.layer.shouldRasterize = YES
```

I think this is due to the blend mode that is used to render the shadow. For example I had a dark background and white text on it and wanted to "highlight" the text using a black shadowy glow. It wasn't working until I set this property.

Comment: This is required to make it faster even with dozens of UILabels in view. Without it, shadows are slow if used with opacity.

Comment: If you plan on using `shouldRasterize`, then make sure you also set the `rasterizationScale` : `label.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;` Or it may look weird on retina screens.

Answer (score 7):

Apply the (soft) shadow on the view's *layer*, like this:

```
UILabel *label = [[UIabel alloc] init];
label.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
label.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
```

Answer (score 7):

To keep things up to date: Creating the shadow in Swift is as easy as that:

Import the QuartzCore Framework

```
import QuartzCore
```

And set the shadow attributes to your label

```
titleLabel.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor()
titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0)
titleLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
titleLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
titleLabel.layer.masksToBounds = false
titleLabel.layer.shouldRasterize = true
```

Comment: Weirdly, that results in a shadow above (in the y direction) the text instead of aligned with it.

Answer (score 5):

```
_nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
_nameLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:19.0f];
_nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_nameLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.2];
_nameLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
```

i think you should use the [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.2] to set the alpha value.

Answer (score 4):

I tried almost all of these techniques (except FXLabel) and couldn't get any of them to work with iOS 7.  I did eventually find THLabel which is working perfectly for me.  I used THLabel in Interface Builder and setup User Defined Runtime Attributes so that it's easy for a non programmer to control the look and feel.

https://github.com/MuscleRumble/THLabel

Answer (score 4):

This like a trick,

```
UILabel *customLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

UIColor *color = [UIColor blueColor];
customLabel.layer.shadowColor = [color CGColor];
customLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
customLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
customLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
customLabel.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

Answer (score 3):

Subclass UILabel, as stated, then, in drawRect:, do `[self drawTextInRect:rect];` to get the text drawn into the current context. Once it is in there, you can start working with it by adding filters and whatnot. If you want to make a drop shadow with what you just drew into the context, you should be able to use:

```
CGContextSetShadowWithColor()
```

Look that function up in the docs to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a library that provides a UILabel subclass with soft shadow support and a bunch of other effects:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXLabel

Answer (score 3):

In `Swift 3`, you can create an extension:

```
import UIKit

extension UILabel {
    func shadow() {
        self.layer.shadowColor = self.textColor.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    }
}
```

and use it via:

```
label.shadow()
```

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 5 Apple provides a private api method to create labels with soft shadows.
The labels are very fast: I'm using dozens at the same time in a series of transparent views and there is no slowdown in scrolling animation.

This is only useful for non-App Store apps (obviously) and you need the header file.

```
$SBBulletinBlurredShadowLabel = NSClassFromString("SBBulletinBlurredShadowLabel");

CGRect frame = CGRectZero;

SBBulletinBlurredShadowLabel *label = [[[$SBBulletinBlurredShadowLabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
label.text = @"I am a label with a soft shadow!";
[label sizeToFit];
```

Comment: You don't want to use this if your app is going to the app store.

Comment: Well, to be fair, he stated that in the answer.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use this with a potential App Store submission ??

Answer (score 0):

While it's impossible to set a blur radius directly on `UILabel`, you definitely could change it by manipulating CALayer.

Just set:

```swift
//Required properties
customLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0 //set shadow radius to your desired value.
customLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0 //Choose an opacity. Make sure it's visible (default is 0.0)

//Other options
customLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
customLabel.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
customLabel.layer.masksToBounds = false
```

What I hope will help someone and other answers failed to clarify is that it **will not work** if you also set UILabel `Shadow Color` property directly on Interface Builder while trying to setup `.layer.shadowRadius`.

So if setting `label.layer.shadowRadius` didn't work, please verify `Shadow Color` for this `UILabel` on Interface Builder. It should be set to `default`. And then, please, if you want a shadow color other than black, set this color also through `.layer` property.

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Subclass UILabel, and override -drawInRect:

Comment: Okay that's the obvious part. Then what?