# UITextField: Make it higher and position input text vertically centered

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uitextfield, alignment

The default height of a `UITextField` with border style `UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect` is 31px. For an iPad App, I'd like to make a UITextField with a height of 60px and position the text vertically centered so that it looks good (by default the text is drawn only a few pixel below the top border of the UITextField).

If i do the following...

```
UITextField *txtLogin = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200,200,300,60)];
txtLogin.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
```

...the result looks like this: http://grab.by/6jRc

As you can see, the input text is not vertically centered. I tried to find a solution and found out that I just have to inherit my own custom class from UITextField and override the `- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds` method.
However, this method is never called and according to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920783/drawtextinrect-on-uitextfield-not-called) there is a bug in Apple's API. Therefore I'm looking for alternatives that work.

What would be a good solution to solve this problem and achieve correct vertical alignment for input text?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[txtLogin setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];