# attributedPlaceholder font change

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am trying to change the font of my placeholder but although the placeholder text appears, the font is the standard. Im using the following method to set up my UITextField:

```
    UITextField *name = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 0, frame.size.width - 50, 50)];
    name.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    name.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UITextField_orange.png"];
    name.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Name" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:@"Champagne&Limousines"}];;
    [self addSubview:name];
```

Comment: See [this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031678/uitextfield-attributedplaceholder-has-no-effect

Seems like you ask same question

Answer (score 1):

The value that goes with the `NSFontAttributeName` key should be a `UIFont` object:

```
name.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Name" attributes: @{
  NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Champagne&Limousines" size:12]
}];
```