# UITextField drawTextInRect is never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, xcode9-beta

I've install iOS11 beta5 and catch some problems. I override [`drawTextInRect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619587-drawtextinrect) method for my custom UITextField, but it is never called.

**Note:** yes, i've already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920783/drawtextinrect-on-uitextfield-not-called) answer, but it is works fine on 10.3.

Code sample to reproduce that behavior:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>  

@interface MYCustomTextField : UITextField  

@end  

@implementation MYCustomTextField  

-(void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {  
  [super drawTextInRect:rect];  
  NSLog(@"drawTextInRect calling");  
}  

@end
```

I've also created a [new thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/255155#255155) on Apple's developer forum.

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920783/drawtextinrect-on-uitextfield-not-called

Comment: Possible duplicate of [drawTextInRect on UITextField not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920783/drawtextinrect-on-uitextfield-not-called)

Comment: I've already said that it works correct on iOS 10.3 with xCode 8

Comment: Moreover, `drawPlaceholderInRect` works properly

Comment: You are not the only one, I have this being called for some UILabels and not others, only in iOS11.

This is NOT a dupe, stop posting that. This is iOS11 specific.

Answer (score -1):

drawTextInRect will never called for UITextField. You have to use UILabel for that.

Comment: So why it works on iOS 10.3 with xcode8? @swapnil patel

Comment: drawTextInRect/drawText(in:) should work on a UITextField. Apple mention this function in the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619587-drawtext?changes=latest_minor). And I'm having the exact same issue, worked in Xcode 8/iOS 10, doesn't work in Xcode 9/iOS 11. The draw(_ rect: CGRect) function is being called, but it still draws text on top of that.

Comment: @ChristopherHannah drawRect not actualy the same. Its called for me only once, and do not redraw for example after resign focus.