# How to achieve this font appearance?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, fonts, label

How can I acheive a font like this?

[image]

It's the name below icons on the iOS platform.  Is it Helvetica, and how can I achieve the soft shadow that it has in code?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274168/drop-shadow-on-uitextfield-text/1537079#1537079) may help. And yes, it's Helvetica.

Comment: I think you'll find it's Helvetica on the iPhone/iPhone 3/GS, and Helvetica Neue on the iPhone 4.

Comment: @Steven Fisher Both Helvetica and Helvetica Neue are available on the iPhone, as I understand it: http://iosfonts.com/

Comment: @Matthew Fredrick I think Steven meant that the font on the title below icons on the three phones have a different font, although they all have the capability to use both Helvetica and Helvetica Neue.

Comment: @Steven Fisher: My mind is blown.

Comment: @sudo rm -rf Ah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposting my comment here as requested:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274168/drop-shadow-on-uitextfield-text/1537079#1537079) may help.

As discussed in the comments, that font is indeed Helvetica, *at least on standard-resolution devices*. I'm not too sure if it's Neue Helvetica on retina display devices.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the answer!  I hesitate to use quartz because of speed issues, but it gives the appearance I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't be too much of a problem actually. iPhone draws stuff relatively quickly and smoothly... compared to some other mobile devices.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using Quartz 2D.

> A shadow is an image painted
>   underneath, and offset from, a
>   graphics object such that the shadow
>   mimics the effect of a light source
>   cast on the graphics object, as shown
>   in Figure 7-1. **Text can also be
>   shadowed**. Shadows can make an image
>   appear three dimensional or as if it’s
>   floating.

look here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadows/dq_shadows.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH208-TPXREF101

good luck

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

BoltClock answered it already in a comment. Follow his link.

(I just discovered he said the same thing, but I want to draw attention to it so I'll leave this answer -- just don't check it, or BoltClock, add it as answer.)

---

**[This answer to a previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274168/drop-shadow-on-uitextfield-text/1537079#1537079)** explains how to do it. Turns out it's pretty simple.

Comment: I voted you up, actually :) (I don't like posting these kinds of links as answers, but if someone does I'll definitely give them my vote.)

Comment: @BoltClock If you could add your comment as an answer I'd accept it as the right one since I believe you got the answer first.

Comment: @BoltClock Yeah, I'm just now realizing that links to perfectly good answers here on SO are more appropriately comments. It's taken a bit to pick up some of the unstated protocols. :)

Comment: Since both of you requested I add it as my own answer, how could I say no? I'll leave my vote on your answer there though :)

Comment: Not sure what the standard procedure is here, sorry if it's against standard system to ask for an answer from a comment. :)

Comment: @sudo rm -rf: It's OK, it's simply my personal policy not to post a link to another answer and call it my own answer. If someone asks me to I guess I won't mind.