# How to create letterpress effect?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm looking to implement something like the famous "letterpress" effect in my application.  Here's what I'm talking about: (just a quick example made in PShop)
[image: Letterpress effect]

As you can see, it looks like it's pressed into the background.  I wonder if it's possible to do something like this on the Mac *dynamically*.  Is there a way?  Thanks!

Comment: If you really need this effect, and there is no other solution available, you can always use separate PNG files for every character and merge them together. Ugly, but it works :)

Comment: @Anne: I was thinking I could make a custom font to do the job, but I don't really know how I'd go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the gradient fill portion of the text using the code I provide in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266179/how-do-i-add-a-gradient-to-the-text-of-a-uilabel-but-not-the-background/1267638#1267638).  Check the coordinate space first, because I described that for the iPhone, which has an inverted Y axis when compared to the Mac's normal Quartz coordinates.

The text is first used to create a clipping path, and the gradient is drawn within that path.

As far as the internal shadow, you might be able to draw this after the gradient is drawn by using `CGContextSetShadowWithColor()` with an appropriate downward offset and black color, then drawing the text again using just the stroke of the text.  deanWombourne has some sample code for a similar task in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274168/drop-shadow-on-uitextfield-text/1537079#1537079).

Comment: Ah, that's more what I was thinking of.  Thanks, Brad!

Answer (score 1):

1. Draw the text with a normal font to create a black and white bitmap of the text.
2. Draw another image that is is the same size and completely filled with the gray-to-white gradient you have above.
3. Create a completely white image with the same size as your other images.
4. Draw your back and white text image (1) onto the white image (3) with NSCompositeDestinationOut.

This gives you a white image with your text cut out.

Draw the white image with the text cut out on top of the gradient image and apply a shadow while drawing.

Comment: That seems intense.  I'll probably pass on it for now unless there is an easier way, as it seems like overkill and processor-intensive for just displaying text.

Comment: It is definitely a PITA but it isn't really processor intensive.