# iphone - Animation's performance is very poor when view's shadow is on

Tags: iphone, performance, ipad, animation, shadow

I have a `UILabel` with `CALayer` shadow on.And I just move it around via `UIView` animation.

The performance is poor and I can see the animation is not smooth at all.

I think it is the shadow of the `UILabel` which causes the animation problem because if I turn the shadow off, the animation becomes as smooth as normal.

I have tried using `view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;`

But still the animation performance is there.

Anyone can give me some hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can greatly improve the performance of a CALayer’s shadow by using its `shadowPath` property—this allows it to draw the shadow without having to recalculate the alpha mask of the layer. For a rectangular view, you’d use it like this:

```
theView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:theView.bounds].CGPath;
```

or, if its corners are rounded,

```
theView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:theView.bounds cornerRadius:theView.layer.cornerRadius].CGPath;
```

Note that this is a shadow around the view’s borders—if you want better performance on the shadow on the text itself, you either need to use the label’s text-shadow properties (which sacrifice the niceties of CALayer shadows, like blur, for better rendering speed) or—a much more complicated option—create a CGPathRef to use as the layer’s `shadowPath` from the text glyphs themselves.

Comment: Yeah it worked. theView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:theView.bounds].CGPath; improves my performance very much. It is quite smooth now. Thanks

Comment: Where is this text shadow property?

Comment: @PsychoDad: It’s actually two properties, `shadowColor` and `shadowOffset`.

Comment: Using a shadow path means Core Animation doesn’t have to render out your layer’s opacity mask to have something to blur into a shadow; it can just draw the shadow using the known shape. I don’t know the implementation details, but it’s dramatically faster to do the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer you're looking for but I found this: [Drop Shadow on UITextField text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274168/drop-shadow-on-uitextfield-text/1537079#1537079)

It may be better performance, I haven't tried it but it seems it would be.