# CALayer - Shadow causes a performance hit?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, calayer, shadow

So I am doing some custom animations on my navigationcontroller and the way it pushes and pops the viewControllers.

Everything runs smooth. As soon as I add the following code (In a subclass of `UINavigationController`), I face a huge performance hit. After adding a shadow all animations become very laggy. Is this expected or am I doing something wrong in the code?

```
// This code gets called once during NavigationController initialization.
[self.view setClipsToBounds:NO];
[self.view.layer setCornerRadius:5];
[self.view.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 20)];
[self.view.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor]];
[self.view.layer setShadowRadius:20.0];
[self.view.layer setShadowOpacity:1];
```

**EDIT:**

Changed my shadow radius to 1 and it's still slow

Comment: For all it's worth, this is covered explicitly in WWDC 2010 Session 425: Core Animation in Practice, Part 2
[here.](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2010__sd/session_426__core_image_effects_and_optimization.mov)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You should expect a slowdown from adding a shadow. A `shadowRadius` of 20 is very high and will be especially slow.

The other key to improve shadow rendering speed: set the [`shadowPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/shadowPath) property. It can help dramatically.

Comment: setting ShadowPath did the trick, My shadow radius is 10 and it still performs well.

Comment: @NicolasManzini More tips for shadow performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10133109/fastest-way-to-do-shadows-on-ios/10133182#10133182

Comment: it's much efficient way that I test... idea with shouldRasterize work not so quick as it can be needed. this answer is much better! don't understand why @williamcotton answer gain so much votes...

Comment: shadowPath did the trick. performance feels a million times better!

Answer (score 89):

```
self.view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
self.view.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen.scale;
```

I was recently having some issues with slow CALayer shadows, and that simple line of code fixed up everything for me!

Comment: awesome, this makes it perform even better, now I can have any size of shadowRadius without having a performance hit

Comment: This will ignore the retina images that you may have for you annotation. To fix this, add the following line: self.view.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with a tableView where each cell contains a few UILabels as well as a view with rounded corners. I added a shadow to the layer that contains the tableView and the scrolling becomes choppy. However, setting shouldRasterize = YES resolved the choppiness but pixelated the view (visibly blurry) so it's not an acceptable solution. I found using shadowPath instead of shadowOffset did the trick.

Comment: it could be worse if the view varies. shouldRasterize = YES is only a good solution when the view does not change, so bitmap is genereated once once and cached and reused by UIScrollView

Comment: Please note that this increases your RAM usage

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was after! Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

Using `shadowPath` instead of `shadowOffset`.

```
theView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:theView.bounds].CGPath;
```

Check this post: [iphone - Animation's performance is very poor when view's shadow is on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746921/iphone-animations-performance-is-very-poor-when-views-shadow-is-on)

Comment: Worked like a charm, better than shouldRasterize which blurred the view and all sublayers.

Comment: it's much efficient way that I test... idea with shouldRasterize work not so quick as it can be needed. this answer is much better! don't understand why @williamcotton answer gain so much votes...

Comment: shadowPath is pretty good and fast, but how can keep update frame in autolayout?

Comment: This is only if you don't have rounded corners or transparency in your views. Not every views is rectangular. `shouldRasterize` is more generic and we don't have to deal with any bezier paths as said.

Comment: @TomSawyer do it in view's layoutSubviews, maybe you need subclass some views

Answer (score 2):

Yes, shadow's are very expensive (especially a shadow that big -- play with the radius and you'll notice it makes a huge difference in the degree of slowdown you experience). One way to improve performance is to render it once to a `CGImageContext` and just display that image instead of having the layer re-render the shadow every time it redraws (but this doesn't work if the shadow needs to animate or something).

Comment: You think it would perform better to use an actual png and add it to my UIView?

Comment: If that's a possibility (ie you know the shape/size/whatever of the shadow beforehand) then it would definitely give you better performance. Blitting images is much faster than rendering shadows.

Comment: Prerendered to an image will work as long as yuo don't need to change the shadow shape.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.3. add this code.

> myView -> UIView, collectionViewCell or tableViewCell can be.

```
myview.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: cell.bounds).cgPath
myview.layer.shouldRasterize = true
myview.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm coding app with "Neumorphism" style, so much shadow and app so laggy. But use this code below, app very smooth.

```
viewHasShadow.layer.shouldRasterize = true
viewHasShadow.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```