# Shadows slow up UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` that pretty much functions like a Facebook **news feed**. I thought my elements were slowing the scroll fps down. By process of elimination, I found out that the **shadows slow down** my app.

The `UIView` boxes inside the scroll view have such configuration:

```
self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2)
self.layer.shadowRadius = 2
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.15
```

Like a news feed, my scroll view has many boxes, therefore having `UIView`s with their own shadows. How do I go with this without slowing down my app?

Comment: self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;

Comment: It worked and it did speed things up. However, all the subviews (mostly `UILabel`s) became blurry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a bunch of stuff on speeding up UIScrollViews:

- [CALayer - Shadow causes a performance hit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997972/calayer-shadow-causes-a-performance-hit)
- https://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/on-the-importance-of-setting-shadowpath/

If you use custom CALayer instances -- especially with shadows -- stuff that requires processing power, you should use

```
scrollView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
scrollView.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

Also a `shadowPath` could speed up your scrollview as well something like this:

```
[scrollView.layer setShadowPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:myView.bounds] CGPath]];
```

Setting a shadowPath allows iOS to not recalculate how it should draw the shadow every time it draws the view, thus improving performance.

In swift, something like this:

```
let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: view.bounds);
view.layer.masksToBounds = false;
view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor;
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0.5);
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;
view.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
```

Comment: Would you say that `.shouldRasterize` and `.rasterizationScale` are enough? Could you also write a Swift equivalent for the code (especially the `setShadowPath` line)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `shadowPath` will improve performance and look the same so long as your views are opaque. You could just set it to the bounds of the view or layer like so:

```
CGPathRef shadowPath = CGPathCreateWithRect(self.bounds, NULL);
self.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath;
CGPathRelease(shadowPath);
```

In Swift:

```
layer.shadowPath = CGPathCreateWithRect(bounds, nil)
```

The memory management is handled for you (discussed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_53)).

Comment: Could you write a Swift equivalent, please? Especially the line with `CGPathRelease`. Thank you!