# How to add shadow on UITextField with round Corners?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to achieve a shadow on `UITextField` with round corners like below image: [image]

My Code as below:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       textField.layer.cornerRadius =             textField.frame.size.height / 2
       textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
       textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.3).cgColor
       textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
       textField.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
       textField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }
```

but, I think something is missing...

**Output:** 
[image]

thanks in advance!

Comment: This adds a **border**, not a shadow.

Comment: yaa.. but how to add shadow??@the4kman

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop Shadow on UITextField text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274168/drop-shadow-on-uitextfield-text)

Comment: @UdayBabariya add this line self.textfiledDemo.borderStyle = .none

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try below code to achieve shadow effect on `roundRect` textfield.

```
    //Basic texfield Setup 
    textField.borderStyle = .none
    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground // Use anycolor that give you a 2d look.

    //To apply corner radius
    textField.layer.cornerRadius = textField.frame.size.height / 2

    //To apply border
    textField.layer.borderWidth = 0.25
    textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

    //To apply Shadow
    textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    textField.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0
    textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero // Use any CGSize
    textField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor

    //To apply padding
    let paddingView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: textField.frame.height))
    textField.leftView = paddingView
    textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
```

**Note:** For some reason `textField.borderStyle = .none` not taking effect even setting the code in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.So, I recommend you to set borderStyle through storyBoard textfield `Attributes inspector`.

[image]

**Output from real device:**

[image]

**To achieve a drop shadow effect:**(like other **`SO`** posts)

```
   textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.25).cgColor
   textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
   textField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor //Any dark color
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add this extension and then use the method "addShadow" to add shadow to you Textfield, label, textview and etc...

```
extension UIView {    
func addShadow(shadowColor: CGColor = UIColor.black.cgColor,
                   shadowOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 2.0),
                   shadowOpacity: Float = 0.4,
                   shadowRadius: CGFloat = 3.0) {
        layer.shadowColor = shadowColor
        layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
        layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        layer.masksToBounds = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this below code

```
    textfield.layer.cornerRadius = textfield.frame.size.height/2
    textfield.clipsToBounds = false
    textfield.layer.shadowOpacity=0.4
    textfield.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
```

**OutPut:**

[image]

Comment: its showing outer line of textfield...check my output.

Comment: @UdayBabariya remove border width and color and use textfield white and view behind the textfield is white so that you can examine clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
textField.layer.masksToBounds = false
textField.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
textField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
```